# How to implement PayPal payments without creating accounts for all users?

Tags: reactjs, spring-boot, paypal, payment

I am working on an university project about buying items. Each user in the app can add an item for sale and that user can also buy other item at the same time from another user. I have to add PayPal integration to the project. The problem is that I don't know how to start with the implementation. I don't want to create PayPal accounts for all users. Is there a way to send money having only the IBAN or something like that. I also don't understand when a user adds a new item for sale, does he have to add also card number or IBAN or something like that(and store it in the db), so other users who buy this item will send money to this card.

The backend is in Spring Boot and the frontend is in React.
Any help would be apreciated.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

A [standard PayPal Checkout integration](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/standard/integrate/) ([react version](https://paypal.github.io/react-paypal-js/?path=/story/example-paypalbuttons--default)) accepts guest payments using a credit card for most of the world, and from payers with a German IP address SEPA with an IBAN is also accepted.

If you want the receiver of the payment to be something other than the account processing the payment, you can [specify a `payee` parameter](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/standard/customize/pay-another-account/) when creating the order, which can be an email_address.

If that receiver email address does not correspond to one with an existing PayPal account, they'll be notified and the receiver has 30 days to create one to claim it (and can then withdraw it to a bank or do whatever they want with it). Reminders are sent. Unclaimed payments are automatically refunded after 30 days.